# IIS utf 8 url encoding with php doesn't work

Tags: php, iis, symfony, utf-8, fastcgi

I have a symfony2 application which I want to host on IIS the problem is that apparently fastcgi doesn't understand utf8 characters in url and doesn't pass them to symfony therefore the application isn't working. 
How can I fix this behavior and make it work?

P.S. : The application runs fine on Apache 
P.S. 2: When I try to install this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918) it gives me the error of "the certificate of the signer of this message is invalid" !!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't find a decent fix for my problem, but since I didn't use the url parameters for routing and they are only there to help with the SEO, I used the .* wildcard in url.
hope this helps someone